# Prove $\sin(x)$ to be periodic?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove periodicity of $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ starting from the Taylor series expansion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63102/how-to-prove-periodicity-of-sinx-or-cosx-starting-from-the-taylor-seri)

With only $f(x)=x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!+ \cdots$, how to prove that $f(x)$ is periodic (there is a $k$ such that $f(x)=f(x+k)$ for all $x$) and to find a formula for $k$?

And how to prove that $f(x)$ converges for all $x$?

Comment: Read the prologue on the exponential function in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

Comment: "how to prove that f(x) converges for all x?" - you compute the [radius of convergence](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Radius_of_convergence).

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61845).

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate, feel free to delete/close