# Period of $\sin(x) + \cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

The period of $\sin(x)$ is $2\pi$ and $\cos(x)$ is $2\pi$.

And the period of $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ is also $2\pi$.

Why it is so?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by why? How are you defining $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: Suppose the period of a function $f(x)$ is $h$.  Then, by the definition of the period of a function, we have $f(x+h)=f(x)$.  How does this work out when we have a sum of functions $f(x),g(x)$?

Comment: What is the definition of period of a function?

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/80384/8581  :-)

Answer (score 9):

There is something different about the function $$\sin x+\cos x= \sqrt 2(\frac{\sqrt 2}2\sin x+\frac {\sqrt 2} 2\cos x)=\sqrt 2(\cos \frac {\pi}4\sin x+\sin\frac {\pi}4\cos x)=\sqrt 2\sin (x+\frac {\pi}4)$$- it is not the period of the function, which remains $2\pi$, but the amplitude.

Comment: This is the better way because it proves that the period cannot be smaller than $2\pi $ as well.

Comment: Perhaps I should also have mentioned that the $\frac {\pi}4$ is a phase shift.

Answer (score 2):

To find the period of a function:

Given $$\sin(kx)$$
or $$\cos(kx)$$

So, the period will be $$\frac{2\pi}{k}$$

Now for $$\cos x + \sin x$$

Now, see that we must have an integral number of periods between $\sin x$ and $\cos x$

So, for positive integers $m$ and $n$:

$$2\pi m = 2\pi n$$

This can be satisfied if $m = n =1$

So the period is thus $2\pi$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$. Then

$$f(x + 2\pi) = \sin(x + 2\pi) + \cos(x + 2\pi) = \sin(x) + \cos(x) = f(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

because
$$\sin(x+2\pi)+\cos(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$

Comment: I see this as a proof that $2\pi$ is **a** period. The OP speaks of **the** period. It must be shown also that values between $0$ and $2\pi$ are not periods.

Comment: By the same logic, $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ would have a period of $2\pi$ as well. But it doesn't; it has a period of $\pi$. (Proof: Remember that $\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac12\sin(2x)$)